# Is right hand thumb rule applied differently in a circular loop compared to a straight wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

tl;dr - the title

So I was pretty sure if the current is going downwards the direction of the magnetic field is clockwise and when it is going upwards the direction of magnetic field is anti-clockwise..

But there is a question for which I searched numerous websites and they all had a similar diagram in their solution, and I am confused by how they are applying the rule, according to me its wrong and it should be the opposite. ( refer attached image ) [image: wait what description]

So in this image if you look at the left side of the loop the current is going upwards but still the direction of the magnetic field is being taken as clockwise so what is going on?? ( same with the right side of the loop ). When I am applying the right hand thumb rule myself then according to that the direction of the magnetic field on both sides should be the opposite of what it is in the diagram.

But I've usually only applied the rule in a straight current carrying conductor so I'm wondering if it is different for circular loops??

Comment: The right hand thumb rule works fine when I apply to the diagram. Note that the loop is on the surface of a table so it is horizontal and not going up or down.

Comment: "So in this image if you look at the left side of the loop the current is going upwards but still the direction of the magnetic field is being taken as clockwise so what is going on?" - it's not going upwards, its horizontal, lying flat on the table. The magnetic field lines are viewed "from below" on the left (align your thumb with the wire, point it in the direction of the current, and curl your fingers - the CW/CCW appearance depends on where you're looking from).

Comment: "Upwards" and "clockwise" are confusing words because they depend on where you look from. Just use the right hand rule.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, if you point your right thumb in the direction of current flow, and loosely clinch your right fist, your fingers will be curling in the same direction as the magnetic field, if your "curling direction" is down your fingers and towards your finger tips.